# jquery multiselect tree view count of selected item

Tags: jquery, treeview

I am using jquery multiselect tree view and want to show count but the count doesnt show poperly . The tree - view I am using is http://jquer.in/jquery-plugins-for-html5-forms/tree-multiselect-js/

I found this code  -

```
<div id="count"></div>

var countChecked = function() {
  var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
    $( "#count" ).text( n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!" );
 };
 countChecked();

 $( ".title input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", countChecked );
```

But it doesnt show correct count. How do I do this

Comment: When you say 'I've found this code', does that mean that you've just copy-pasted some random code you've found online and that's it? Maybe you want to put some more time into it so you understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am a beginner. so dont know much but I have tried a lot. I work and I have  to deliver this so I don't have much time thats why I need little guidance if you can suggest what I can do more to implement this. I understand the code I am using but dont know how to make it work the count it shows is wrong.. plz help